# Replicate and sync database MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, go-gorm

I'm trying to create a system that copies data from another database of another application, applies some restructuring and saves it.
I want to keep the IDs the same as the original however using GORM, I cannot set the column name as ID otherwise it will always ignore my passed ID and use an auto-incremented one.

I've tried to create a different id field and set it as primary key and it does let me keep the passed IDs, however I'm struggling to getting upset to work properly.

```
type User struct {
    EID          uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ID           uint
    Username     string `gorm:"unique"`
}

user := User{
    ID: 133,
    Username: "example",
}

db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
    Columns:   []clause.Column{{Name: "id"}},
    DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"username"}),
}).Create(&user)
```

The example above is an example that always leads to creating a new record instead of updating the existing one.

Any tips on making it not creating a new record and instead updating the existing one?

Comment: *"Any tips?"* isn't a specific enough question for Stack Overflow. What are you actually asking? What about what you have isn't working? If you're getting an error, what is that error? If is isn't doing what you want/expect, what*is* it doing and what should it be?

Comment: @Larnu edited it, though I think it was pretty explanatory to someone who read everything and not just the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, composite keys kept the passed values and if passed the attribute autoIncrement:false, it also stopped the ID named columns from auto-incrementing and keeping the passed values. So in order to keep the keys in tables with single primary keys, I created a dummy key in the model/struct that I never populated leading to saving the keys that I passed.

```
type User struct {
    DummyKey      uint   `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    ID           uint   `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
}

user := User{
    ID: 133,
    Username: "example",
}

db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
    DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"username"}),
}).Create(&user)
```

I also removed the columns attribute from the upsert since it wasn't taking into consideration any of the parameter I set there. It seems to work well with the primary keys alone.